# Installing Gearman on MAMP PRO and OSX

Tags: php, mamp

I'm trying to install Gearman on OSX (10.8.3) and MAMP PRO (2.1.1), but for some reason it's not picking up my gearman.so extension file and loading it - I can't see it in phpinfo(). I followed the steps that seem to have worked for others:

Installing Gearman:

> brew install gearman

Downloading and installing the Gearman package:

> tar xzf gearman-X.Y.tgz
>   cd gearman-X.Y
>   phpize
>   ./configure
>   make
>   make install

Both of these seemed to work correctly. I copying the gearman.so file to the extensions directory shown in phpinfo(), and added:

> extension=gearman.so

To the MAMP PHP 5.4.4 php.ini template. I restart MAMP and open up phpinfo() again but it doesn't show anything to do with Gearman. If I look at the loaded php.ini file, gearman.so is listed there, and is in the extensions directory shown, but it still isn't loading.

Why wouldn't an extension show up after these steps? Any idea how I can troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you placed the gearman.so in the right folder for MAMP and make sure you did sudo make install and not just make install

I know this is old but wanted to leave a comment incase someone else found this in their search